# lookup specific rows in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df.

```
df
ColA  ColB
A      PQ
A      WE
B      PQ
B      YU
```

```
df <- data.frame(ColA=c("A","A","B","B"),ColB = c("PQ","WE","PQ","YU"))
```

Expected output should be only specific to "PQ"

So

```
df
ColA  ColB    ColC
A      PQ      PQ
A      WE      PQ
B      PQ      PQ
B      YU      PQ
```

Comment: What do you mean here? `ColC` does not exist in your original `df`. Also, it would be nice if you provide code that we can run, i.e. reproducible code.

Comment: Like we need to create a new column. So A corresponds to PQ and B corresponds to PQ as well. I have added a code for you

Comment: Your logic isn't totally clear, so posting the code you've tried so far might help folks understand how you're defining this. Right now your title seems like you're asking how to subset data, which there are many SO posts on already, but all I can see changing between the two data frames is adding a column with all one value

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
df <- data.frame(ColA = c('A','A','B','B'), 
             ColB = c('PQ','WE','PQ','YU'), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$colC <- ifelse(df$ColB == 'PQ','PQ',df$ColB)
```

Given your explanation, if ColB has 'PQ' then ColC is 'PQ', any other case is just the value of ColB.

Comment: Thanks for the time. The logic is it should fetch from the dataframe it self. Like A corresponds to PQ. I mean its a kind of vlookup

Comment: Hi @imran p, let me understand, first row since ColB has PQ, then ColC = PQ, second row doesn't have PQ in ColA or ColB, then should I input the PQ value anyway?

Comment: Yes, since one of the values A and B corresponds to PQ

Comment: By the way, ColA doesn't have a PQ value, just 'A' or 'B'

Comment: Let me explain in detail. in ColA, for A , the one of the values is PQ. So I need only this specific value called PQ in ColC and nothing else. Hope this helps :)

Comment: ok, but in ColA there is a value 'B'. In this case, you want 'PQ' anyway? See that your ColC has all the values 'PQ'

Comment: Ok so, even B has one of the value as PQ. So it should be PQ.

Comment: last row has ColA = 'B', ColB = 'YU' but even in this case the ColC = 'PQ'. In fact all your ColC responses are 'PQ'. What would it be the criteria?

Comment: I'm sorry if I don't understand well your question, if ColA is 'A' or 'B' and ColB is 'PQ', 'WE' or 'YU', it is 'PQ' in any of that cases. Perhaps you can explain in which cases ColC is not 'PQ'?

Comment: Let me say for example for B we do not have PQ at all. B only has YU and ME. Ok? Now I may be need only YU in ColC corresponding to B in ColA. Makes sense? A should have PQ only in ColC

Comment: I have post an answer, please review your original question posted as it doesn't consider the case where ColC is not 'PQ'